# "They had agreed to go" or "agreed to go to?"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

What's the correct  construction when the *go* ends with a punctuation? Example:

> At the alleyway they'd agreed to go (to), Mary spotted many tiny bars.

Is the "to" needed? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the alleyway they'd agreed to go

This by itself is a complete sentence. It means that while in the alleyway, they agreed to go.

> Marry spotted many tiny bars

This is also a complete sentence.

The issue with removing "to" from this sentence is the punctuation. Without the "to", the comma would need to be a semicolon to divide the two sentences. This would, however, change the meaning of the sentence.

With sentences like these, it sometimes helps to reorder them. For example,

> At the alleyway they'd agreed to go **to**, Mary spotted many tiny bars.

becomes

> Mary spotted many tiny bars at the alleyway they'd agreed to go **to**.

"they'd agreed to go to" is using "to" to specify the alley as a destination, not some other feature of "to." Removing it would result in a sentence like "I will go your house" or "You go the wrong way" which are both wrong because go is [rarely used in a transitive sense](https://www.englishforums.com/English/GoAsTransitive/mxlqn/post.htm) (when it is, it usually means to choose or buy something, but it is informal). The transitive meaning of "go" does not work here, so the "to" is required.